# Broadcasting Intent from one app to another

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am making an app that uses a third party app called Arduino Uno Communicator to send data to an Arduino board from the Android Tablet using usb serial communication.  I have a java file called DrawView that extends View.  With this class I can essentially draw a path, gather points from the path, put those points in a string and then call a static method in my MainActivity and pass my string to that method. My code for this part looks like this:

```
public class DrawView extends View 
  {
     MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity();
     private String waypoints; 

     //declare variables here...

     public DrawView(Contex context, AttributeSet attrs) 
       {
         super(context, attrs); 

         //setup my paint, canvas and path here...

       }

     @Override
     public onDraw(Canvas canvas)
       {
         //draw canvas here...
       }

     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
       {
          //declare variables...

          switch(event.getAction())
            {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                //start adding to waypoints string...

                return true; 

              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                //add to waypoints
                break; 

              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                //pass string to static method called main in MainActivity
                mActivity.main(waypoints); 

                break; 

              default:
                return false; 
            }

            return true; 
          }

       }
```

After passing the string to the main method in MainActivity, the main method will then call another method within MainActivity called send.  Previously I thought I could just send from the main method, but I can't since it has to be a static method.  So now I call a non static method by creating an instance of MainActivity like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static String DATA_RECEIVED_INTENT =   "primavera.arduino.intent.action.DATA_RECEIVED";
private final static String SEND_DATA_INTENT = "primavera.arduino.intent.action.SEND_DATA";
private final static String DATA_EXTRA = "primavera.arduino.intent.extra.DATA";

DrawView drawView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawView = new DrawView(this, null);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

}

public static void main(String in) {

    MainActivity d = new MainActivity();
    d.send(in);
}

private void send(String in) {

    byte[] data = in.getBytes(); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(SEND_DATA_INTENT);
    intent.putExtra(DATA_EXTRA, data);
    sendBroadcast(intent);

}

}
```

I have checked that all the methods are being properly called.  The waypoints string is correct.  The only thing that seems to not be working is broadcasting the intent.  If I comment the part where the main method is called in the DrawView file and I put a button on the screen and put this code for the button:

```
public void buttonSend (View view) {

    byte[] data = "Hello".getBytes(); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(SEND_DATA_INTENT);
    intent.putExtra(DATA_EXTRA, data);
    sendBroadcast(intent);

}
```

The string will send just fine.

Comment: how do you know its not working? How are you handling the broadcast receiver in another app?

Comment: The source code for the other app is here https://github.com/jeppsson/Arduino-Communicator. I have used this method and have been able to send data to the Arduino.  Only when I try to broadcast the intent from this method does it fail to work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Instead of trying to pass the String from the DrawView class to the main method in MainActivity, I decided to right a method in DrawView that when called would return a String.  After I would get done drawing the path and the points were all added to the waypoints String, I simply created a new static String and returned it.  Once I did this the Arduino received all of the sent data.